# C# struct serialization in different applications (WPF and Unity) returns byte array of different sizes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, serialization

I have a dll that has structs definitions and also few functions to serialize and de-serialize them. I wanted to put these in a dll so the exact same structs could be shared among different apps.

The dll is shared by a WPF application (that sends the serialized data via MQTT) and a HoloLens app (developed with Unity and VS), which receives that data and attempts to de-serialize it by using the same dll.

The problem is that while the **WPF** app serializes the struct, Marshal.SizeOf(str) returns a size of 12. Whereas the exact same dll function in the **Unity C# scripts** app returns a size of 24. Furthermore, the last 12 bytes in the array are all 0.

Therefore, there is an out of range exception when trying to deserialize objects that come from the WPF app because they are half the size expected in the Unity scripts.

This is an example of the struct I am serializing:

```
[Serializable]
public struct SimulationVariableModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the function to serialize the Struct to a byte array:

```
    public static byte[] StrucToByteArray<T>(T str) where T : struct
    {
        // In Unity: size = 24
        // In standalone WPF and UWP application: size = 12
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        byte[] arr = new byte[size];

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        try
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, false);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }

        return arr;
    }
```

And the function to convert the byte array into the original struct:

```
    public static T ByteArrayToStruct<T>(byte[] arr) where T : struct
    {
        T str = default;

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, size);
            str = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, str.GetType());

        } finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }

        return str;
    }
```

This is the event handler that receives the serialized data in Unity and tries to de-serialize it to the original struct:

```
private void Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Topic == NewSimulationVariableTopic) {

        // Dummy item to test that the byte Array length is not due to extra data in e.Message.
        SimulationVariableModel test = new SimulationVariableModel { Name = "Bla", Category = "Bla" };

        // testByteArray.Length = 24
        byte[] testByteArray = StrucToByteArray(test);

        // De-serialization is successful
        test = ByteArrayToStruct<SimulationVariableModel>(testByteArray);

        // e.Message is the result from serialization 
        // using StructToByteArray<SimulationVariableModel>(str) in standalone WPF and UWP app.
        // De -serialization fails because e.Message.Length = 12
        SimulationVariableModel simVar = ByteArrayToStruct<SimulationVariableModel>(e.Message);

        // Logic with SimulationVariableModel
    }
}
```

I am thinking this might be caused by the Unity environment? I tested a UWP standalone app, which serializes the Structs in 12 bytes and not 24.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be happening and how to fix this issue?

Thanks so much.

Comment: strings are notoriously awkward to serialize via "simple" routes like this, because they aren't in-place data; frankly, I wonder if you'd be better off with a well-defined serializer - JSON, protobuf, etc

Comment: I'd guess it's something to do with the `string` datatype being treated as Unicode (2 bytes per char) in one and not in the other (i.e. ASCII, 1 byte per char)?

Comment: I suggest using an interface (instead of  `where T : struct` use `where T : IMySerializable` ) this way you can write your own logic for different data types

Comment: You are directly copying the bytes from memory used by the CLR to represent the struct, which is not "really" serialization, and it will probably only work when "both ends" run in similar environments (i.e. using the same CLR). All that marshalling and pointer handling seems a bit weird to me if you're just trying to serialize data... Have you considered using "traditional" serialization instead? (for example using `XmlSerializer`, `BinaryFormatter` or some kind of JSON library)

Comment: A character in c# is two bytes.  So is the WPF using a WCHAR (two bytes) or CHAR (one byte).  I suspect the you are using for T "char" instead of "byte"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by a few comments, the strings were being treated differently in the two platforms. I solved this specific problem by specifying how the structs are serialized in their definition. Example:

```
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct SimulationVariableModel
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public readonly string Name;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public readonly string Category;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public readonly string Id;

    public SimulationVariableModel(string name, string category, string objectId)
    {
        Name = name;
        Category = category;
        Id = objectId;
    }
}
```

However, for a more robust solution I might be better off using an actual serializer as suggested by Mark Gravell and bassfader.

Cheers!